# Rebuilding project takes an exceptionally long amount of time if using predefined maps?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Compile/Link settings are fairly normal (/O2 for optimization and /LTCG for the linker - this is forced due to using a module compiled with /GL).

I have found the section of code causing the compile time increase, but I do not know how to resolve the problem. Despite the long compile time, the current code actually does work when it finally finishes.

When the following function is removed, the compile time is reduced from 125 seconds to 4 seconds (almost all of the time gain is in the linking phase):

```
static void InitializeItemSlotLists(std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>& HEAD_IDS, std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>& SHOULDER_IDS, std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>& CHEST_IDS, std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>& GLOVE_IDS, std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>& WAIST_IDS, std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>& LEGS_IDS, std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>& FEET_IDS, std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>& WEAPON_1H_IDS, std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>& WEAPON_2H_IDS, std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>& SHIELD_IDS, std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>& OFFHAND_IDS) {
    HEAD_IDS[60202] = 93792;
    HEAD_IDS[60222] = 35113;
    HEAD_IDS[60237] = 81960;
    HEAD_IDS[60243] = 77144;
    HEAD_IDS[60249] = 91486;
    HEAD_IDS[60256] = 91255;
    HEAD_IDS[60258] = 82002;
    HEAD_IDS[60299] = 82025;
    (This continues for 5000 or so more lines.)
}
```

I could load all of this from an external text file at runtime, but honestly that's just adding pointless complexity. Despite how arbitrary the data seems, it is extremely unlikely to change in future.

Is the problem that it is trying to optimize this huge chunk of data? If so, is there a way I can force it to ignore this specific file for optimization (it's in its own .cpp file with its own header to predefine the function)?

Comment: why not use a resource, or a brace initializer

Comment: "This continues for 5000 or so more lines" are you serious?? what this function does? you should try to discover a patern to use for loop or something.

Comment: There is no pattern to the data. A resource sounds like an interesting solution - I am unfamiliar with them though. Brace initializers won't work because the data is not in sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must do this using static data, and you don't want to/can't use the map brace-initializer made available with C++11, the way to avoid the performance hit of the compiler trying to optimize 5000 lines of std::map assignments is to put all that data into a static array somehow, like so:

```
#include <map>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t> IdMap;

struct IdRow {
  uint32_t src;
  uint32_t dst;
};

IdRow InitialHeadIds[] = {
  { 60202, 93792 },
  { 60222, 35113 },
  { 60237, 81960 },
  { 60243, 77144 },
  { 60249, 91486 },
  { 60256, 91255 },
  { 60258, 82002 },
  { 60299, 82025 }
};

static void InitializeItemSlotLists(
    IdMap& HEAD_IDS, IdMap& SHOULDER_IDS, IdMap& CHEST_IDS, IdMap& GLOVE_IDS,
    IdMap& WAIST_IDS, IdMap& LEGS_IDS, IdMap& FEET_IDS, IdMap& WEAPON_1H_IDS,
    IdMap& WEAPON_2H_IDS, IdMap& SHIELD_IDS, IdMap& OFFHAND_IDS) {
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(InitialHeadIds) / sizeof(IdRow); i++) {
    IdRow curr = InitialHeadIds[i];
    HEAD_IDS[curr.src] = curr.dst;
  }
}

int main() {
  IdMap headIds, otherIds;
  InitializeItemSlotLists(
    headIds, otherIds, otherIds, otherIds, otherIds, otherIds, otherIds,
    otherIds, otherIds, otherIds, otherIds);
  return 0;
}
```